# without using only once controller,i want the login request to be executed once

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do the load testing of the pages which can be access after login only.

As I am using Once Only Controller for login request ,when I changed Number of thread- 5 or more,login executes 5 times.
as Once Only Controller works for loopcount so I used loopcount but it slowdown my process and it executes the whole testplan.

My test-plan is:

login thread A- one time execution - how to do it?
http request B- multiple times(by using Number of threads)
http request C- multiple times(by using Number of threads)

What should I use for one time login execution and other successor requests needs to be executed multiple times without using Once Only Controller?

Answer (score 6):

Kindly follow these steps:-

1. In Thread Group put number of threads:5 , Ramp-up:0 , Loop count: 1
2. Put your Login part in Once only controller
3. Right click on Your thread group > add > logic controller > loop controller
4. Now put your http request part in loop controller and set loop count of loop controller how many times you want to run
5. Then run the test you will get whatever you want

The Loop count in "Thread Group" is your full script Loop count not for your Transactions, for your transactions you have to put separate loop count before transaction starts.

Comment: Its working,Thanks a lot. Please reply for my next question of ajax calls in jmeter.

Comment: You are welcome Nidhi :) !! If it was really helpful than you can rate my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please do below

1. Your thread group setting should be below:

A.Number of threads :1
B:Ramp up period : 0 or as per application response.
C:Loop Count :5

2. Put your login request under Only once controller.
3. Request B and Request C should be at thread group Level.ie one step above it.
4. Run the request.

please find [Sample Jmx](http://jmeter.apache.org/demos/OnceOnlyTestPlan.jmx)sample Jmx for your reference Plse try. Hope it resolves your issue.